# Are you able to parse JSON data then convert it into an array?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, koa

I am using `KOA` for my backend calling `json` data from `localhost:3000`, then I need to place that data later into a slider but ordered into an array. All this within a custom `WordPress` theme. I am struggling to make this work as I am new to this. Can anyone help look at my code and see if I can convert into an array within my existing code so I can sort or order the data before placing it into the intended document? I am calling `main.js` where I am keeping the function that calls and formats the data. Here, I will include the `main.js` content as well as the `json` file. Thank you in advance.

insurer.json

```
{
  "insurer1": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "520"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "612"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "723"
    }
  },
  "insurer2": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "425"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "580"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "780"
    }
  },
  "insurer3": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "450"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "543"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "733"
    }
  }
}
```

main.js

```
const insuranceUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/insurances';

    const insuranceContainer = document.querySelector('.insurance');

    let Euro = '&euro;/mes';
    let euro_symbol = '&euro;';

    fetch(insuranceUrl) 
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        var sectionx=document.createElement("section");
        sectionx.classList.add("custom_section");
        var insurer1=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer1.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer1']['basic']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer1']['basic']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>'
                        +'</div>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer1);
        var insurer1=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer1.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer1']['plus']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer1']['plus']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer1);
        var insurer1=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer1.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer3']['full']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer1']['full']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer1);
        var insurer2=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer2.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer2']['basic']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer2']['basic']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>'
                        +'</div>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer2);
        var insurer2=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer2.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer2']['plus']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer2']['plus']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>'
                        +'</div>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer2);
        var insurer2=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer2.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer2']['full']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer2']['full']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>'
                        +'</div>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer2);       
        var insurer3=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer3.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer3']['basic']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer3']['basic']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>'
                        +'</div>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer3);
        var insurer3=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer3.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer3']['plus']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer3']['plus']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>'
                        +'</div>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer3);
        var insurer3=sectionx.cloneNode(true);
        insurer3.innerHTML='<div style="border:1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 15px; min-width: 174px; text-align: left;">'
                        +'<label style="color:#27accd; font-weight:600; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer3']['full']['title']+'</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="color:gray; line-height: 20px;">desde</label>'
                        +'<br />'
                        +'<label style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;">'+data['insurer3']['full']['price_from']+' '+Euro+'</label>'
                        +'</div>';
            insuranceContainer.appendChild(insurer3);
        });
```

Comment: What do you want the array to look like? Do you want each insurer object in the JSON file to be its own element in the array? Each child of the insurer?

Comment: insurer1 basic, lowest price, insurer2 basic, mid price, insurer3 basic, highest price
insurer1 plus, lowest price, insurer2 plus, mid price, insurer3 plus, highest price
insurer1 full, lowest price, insurer3 full, mid price, insurer3, full, highest price
but I am not allowed to manipulate the json data in the original file as the company will change it from time to time.

Comment: In other words, grouped by basic first, then plus then full. Since the prices are already ordered in the JSON, I don't need to sort those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a native JS function that will return an Object's keys. You can use that to achieve this.

Let's say your results are stored in an Object called data

```
const data = {
  "insurer1": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "520"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "612"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "723"
    }
  },
  "insurer2": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "425"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "580"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "780"
    }
  },
  "insurer3": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "450"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "543"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "733"
    }
  }
}
```

From there, you could create a new var called keys and store the Object's keys.

```
let keys = Object.keys(data)
```

Now let's create an empty array to store the parsed results.

```
let resultsArr = [];
```

Now let's iterate through the keys in the object and push the values to the array.

```
keys.forEach(key => {resultsArr.push(data[key])})
```

The resultsArr should now contain your parsed data

Comment: Question: Would I have to add const data =... to the json file or would I do this within the main.js file?

Comment: You shouldn't use `const data =` at all (here). You'll have the object you need after `.then(data => {`. That variable `data` in the function passed to `.then` is what you should be using

Comment: You can omit that step so long as you have the data accessible in your main.js file which it looks like you do in that data reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()`, which returns an array

Assumes the keys aren't important and you are targeting modern browsers

```js
const arr = Object.values(data)

arr.forEach((item,i)=> console.log(`Basic from price #${i+1} = ${item.basic.price_from}`))
```

```html
<script>
const data = {
  "insurer1": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "520"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "612"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "723"
    }
  },
  "insurer2": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "425"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "580"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "780"
    }
  },
  "insurer3": {
    "basic": {
      "title": "3rd Party basic",
      "price_from": "450"
    },
    "plus": {
      "title": "Ample 3rd Party",
      "price_from": "543"
    },
    "full": {
      "title": "High Risk",
      "price_from": "733"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```